# Как проверить переменную типа string на наличие текста в ней

Tags: c#

```
string userText;
if (userText == "null")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вы ещё ничего не написали");
}
```

```
string userText;
if (userText == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вы ещё ничего не написали");
}
```

Оба варианта выдают одно и тоже. 
Как проверить есть ли в переменной типа `string` что-либо или же нет?

Выдаёт:

> "Использование локальной переменной "userText", которой не присвоено значение."

Comment: `string` - переменная ссылочного типа. Если переменной ссылочного типа ничего не присвоено, она будет иметь значение `null`. В приведенном вами коде вы сравниваете `userText` не с `null`, а со строковым литералом `"null"`. Вам нужно просто убрать кавычки - и ваш пример будет работать

Comment: может я делаю что-то не так, но я убрал кавычки и выдаёт все тоже самое

Comment: `string userText = null;`

Comment: аа, ну вот сейчас заработало, попробую, спасибо

Comment: Оставлю это тут: `userText is { Length: >0 }`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это где про такое почитать? Что-то я пропустил.

Comment: @aepot что-то я и забыл, что нельзя использовать непроинициализированные ссылочные переменные. Привык, что среда разработки сама подсказывает, где ошибка компиляции

Comment: @aepot Это новые фичи C# 9, думаю любой источник про нововведения вам скажет, что и как. Используется как `объект is {}` - инициализирован, `объект is { свойство: значение}` - проверяет объект на null и чтоб свойство было с нужным значением. Ну и в добавок к этому `объект is { нужные проверки} or not { нужные проверки} and { нужные проверки }`, короче новые, весьма удобный синтаксис в 9 шарпе)

Comment: @aepot Хм, был не прав. Странно, мне казалось объекты инициализируются дефолтным значением в C#. Что-то я где-то упустил.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда уж `... is not`.

Comment: @aepot Тоже верно, моя задача была показать лишь вариант решения, а сама реализация уже зависит от того, как именно будет дальше применяться все это.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Выдаёт "Использование локальной переменной "userText", которой не
> присвоено значение."

Все локальные переменные должны быть инициализированы, до их использования т.е. им нужно присвоить значение, например `string userText = null;`

Ваша переменная `userText` типа `string` является ссылочной, значит может содержать `null` или пустую строку, но так null НЕ проверяется `userText == "null"`

```
if(userText == null || userText == "")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Вы ещё ничего не написали");
}
```

Короткий аналог

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userText))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вы ещё ничего не написали");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, я попробую

Comment: мне пояснили, что лучше писать не string text = null, а кавычки вместо null и потом использовать if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userText))

Comment: @Rotmayer вот теперь этот ответ содержит в себе все что нужно, можете отметить его галочкой, если считаете его  полезным.

Comment: Можно еще так `!(userText?.Length > 0)`, но так обычно делают, когда обратное условие проверяют. Или как @EvgeniyZ показал `userText is not { Length: >0 }`.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь если не сложно, чтобы новую тему не создавать, то подскажите пожалуйста, если я пишу допустим string name = "Роман", как мне посчитать сколько у меня символов в переменной name?

Comment: через String.Length?

Comment: @Rotmayer да, например `Console.WriteLine(userText.Length)`, но не создавайте новый вопрос по любому поводу. Сначала хорошенько поищите решение.

Comment: спасибо, вы помогли разобраться!

Comment: @Rotmayer поставьте галочку этому ответу :) он по моему мнению ее заслуживает.

Comment: я бы поставил вашим комментариям, но ответ то не ваш)
пс. галочку поставил